# Google Maps V3 in Cordova OnsenUI App (Map displays in Browser but not on Phone)

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show `Google Map V3` in **Cordova App** that uses **OnsenUI**. It displays the Google Map when I run it into browser but when I run it in actual Phone then it shows Blank Screen instead of showing Map.

I have gone through many other posts but problem here seems to be different. Here is the code:

```
//Map initialization  
$timeout(function(){
    alert('Inside Time Out for Google Map');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.7042995, 139.7597564);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    alert('Google Map almost loaded');
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
    $scope.overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    $scope.overlay.draw = function() {}; // empty function required
    $scope.overlay.setMap($scope.map);
    $scope.element = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

},100);

alert('End of MapController');
```

In the above code, execution goes inside timeout function and displays:

```
alert('Inside Time Out for Google Map');
```

But when it encounters this line:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.7042995, 139.7597564);
```

then execution does not proceed.

I have added these access in Cordova config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="*.google.com"/> 
<access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
<access origin="*.gstatic.com"/>
<access origin="maps.google.com*"/>
```

Any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: ummm... did you load the google maps js library? sorry I can't think of other reasons :p

Comment: @kaho
Yea, it is loaded. That is why it displays map in the browser. But not in Mobile thats the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was with **Cordova** `config.xml` file:

I created a new Cordova Project and put `www` folder inside that with my changes and it worked.

**We need to add these configurations in `config.xml` file. Adding only `<access...>` did not work in my case:**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

I was struggling with it since last 18 hours and finally found a way. I hope it will help others also.

Comment: Additional note on your answer:  Cordova 4+ changed the way whitelisting is done.  It is now done via a plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.  As of time of writing, this only impacts iOS and Android devices.